# nested object missing after reducer state change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am trying to update `selectedAnswer` in my state:

```
case "SET_ANSWER": {
  const { selectedAnswer, id } = action.data;

  return {
    videos: state.videos.map(video =>
      video.id === id ? { ...video, selectedAnswer } : video
    ),
    search: { term: "", videos: [] }
  };
}
```

My original state looks like this:

```
videos: [{
bookMarked: false
completed: false
current: 0
description: "ffff"
icon: "administrating-vaccinations"
id: 138
parentId: ""
preview: "ddd"
questions: [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
recapId: "374"
results: {correctAnswers: Array(0), incorrectAnswers: Array(0), totalScore: 0}
selectedAnswer: ""
title: "ddd"
youtubeVideo: "ddd"
}...]
```

However after my reducer updates the state I get undefined for `results`:

```
...
questions: (10) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
recapId: "374"
results: undefined <<<<<<
selectedAnswer: ""
title: "Administering Vaccinations"
youtubeVideo: "P2ZSmFDODG4"
```

Action:

```
    {
    type: "SET_ANSWER"
    data:{
    id: 138
    selectedAnswer: 3}
}
```

Comment: your answer is give me nothing about your problem can you create sandbox ? -
maybe you should return from map method, -
maybe you have typeo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The spread operator doesn't do deep cloning, you will have to do

```
videos: state.videos.map(video =>
      video.id === id ? { ...video, results: {...video.results}, selectedAnswer } : video
    ),
```